# Confusion about flatMapLatest in RxSwift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

I learn the sample code in RxSwift. In the file GithubSignupViewModel1.swift, the definition of validatedUsername is:

```
validatedUsername = input.username //the username is a textfiled.rx_text
    .flatMapLatest { username -> Observable<ValidationResult> in
        print("-------->1:")
        return validationService.validateUsername(username)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .catchErrorJustReturn(.Failed(message: "Error contacting server"))
    }
    .shareReplay(1)
```

the validateUsername method is finally called the following method:

```
func usernameAvailable(username: String) -> Observable<Bool> {
    // this is ofc just mock, but good enough
    print("-------->2:")
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://github.com/\(username.URLEscaped)")!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
    return self.URLSession.rx_response(request)
        .map { (maybeData, response) in
            print("-------->3:")
            return response.statusCode == 404
        }
        .catchErrorJustReturn(false)
}
```

Here is my confusion:

whenever I input a character quickly in the username textfield, message -------->1:, -------->2: showed, and a little later message -------->3: showed, but only showed one -------->3: message.

When I input characters slower, message -------->1:, -------->2:, -------->3: showed successively.

But when I change the flatMapLatest to flatMap, how many characters I input, I will get the same number of -------->3: message.

So how did the flatMapLatest work here?

How the flatMapLatest filter the early response from NSURLResponse ?

---

I read some about the flatMapLatest, but none of them will explain my confusion.

What I saw is something like:

```
let a = Variable(XX)
a.asObservable().flatMapLatest(...)
```

When changed `a.value` to another Variable, the Variable(XX) will not influence the subscriber of a.

But the `input.username` isn't changed, it is always a `testfield.rx_text`! So how the flatMapLatest work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not clear what your confusion is about. Are you questioning the difference between `flatMap` and `flatMapLatest`?  `flatMap` will map to a new `Observable`, and if it needs to `flatMap` again, it will in essence merge the two mapped `Observable`s into one.  If it needs to `flatMap` again, it will merge it again, etc.

With `flatMapLatest`, when a new `Observable` is mapped, it overwrites the last `Observable` if there was one.  There is no merge.

EDIT:
In response to your comment, the reason you aren't seeing any `"------>3:"` print is because those `rx_request` `Observable`s were disposed before they could compete, because `flatMapLatest` received a new element, and this mapped to a new `Observable`. Upon disposal, `rx_request` probably cancels the request and will not run the callback where you're printing. The old `Observable` is disposed because it no longer belongs to anyone when the new one takes its place.

Comment: the `input.name` isn't changed! There's only one `Observable`. The closure in flatMapLatest called every time, but the network request only returned once.

Comment: I got another explanation about `flatMapLatest`, and it solved my confusion. https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/Diagrams . Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

TheDroidsOnDroid's answer is clear for me:

[FlatMapLatest diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzZ3O.jpg)

> Well, flatMap() gets one value, then performs long task, and when it
>   gets the next value, previous task will still finish even when the new
>   value arrives in the middle of the current task. It isn’t really what
>   we need because when we get a new text in the search bar, we want to
>   cancel the previous request and start another. That’s what
>   flatMapLatest() does.

http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/ios/rxswift-examples-3-networking/

You can use RxMarbles app on Appstore to play around with operators.

Answer (score 21):

I find this https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Rx.playground/Pages/Transforming_Operators.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift to be useful

> Transforms the elements emitted by an Observable sequence into Observable sequences, and merges the emissions from both Observable sequences into a single Observable sequence. **This is also useful when, for example, when you have an Observable sequence that itself emits Observable sequences, and you want to be able to react to new emissions from either Observable sequence**. The difference between flatMap and flatMapLatest is, flatMapLatest will only emit elements from the most recent inner Observable sequence.

```
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    struct Player {
        var score: Variable<Int>
    }

    let  = Player(score: Variable(80))
    let  = Player(score: Variable(90))

    let player = Variable()

    player.asObservable()
        .flatMap { $0.score.asObservable() } // Change flatMap to flatMapLatest and observe change in printed output
        .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    .score.value = 85

    player.value = 

    .score.value = 95 // Will be printed when using flatMap, but will not be printed when using flatMapLatest

    .score.value = 100
```

With `flatMap`, we get

```
80
85
90
95
100
```

With `flatMapLatest`, we get

```
80
85
90
100
```

> In this example, using flatMap may have unintended consequences. After
>   assigning  to player.value, .score will begin to emit
>   elements, but the previous inner Observable sequence (.score) will
>   also still emit elements. By changing flatMap to flatMapLatest, only
>   the most recent inner Observable sequence (.score) will emit
>   elements, i.e., setting .score.value to 95 has no effect.
>
> flatMapLatest is actually a combination of the map and switchLatest
>   operators.

Also, I find https://www.raywenderlich.com/158205/rxswift-transforming-operators this to be useful

`flatMap`

> keeps up with each and every observable it creates, one for each element added onto the source observable

`flatMapLatest`

> What makes flatMapLatest different is that it will automatically switch to the latest observable and unsubscribe from the the previous one.

Answer (score 8):

I think this diagram from [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158205/rxswift-transforming-operators) can help.

[image: flatMapLatest diagram]

Answer (score 0):

So if we think about an event being emitted from a search box as the user types each time an event is received `flatMap` would fire off a separate request even if a current request is in flight. `flatMapLatest` in contrast disposes of the first stream. In the wrapper around URLSession this calls cancel on the request. So if you type really quickly you should see fewer requests returning. There's a brilliant video explaining just this here: https://youtu.be/z8ukiv5flcw . Here's the source to the wrapper around URLSession (notice `task.cancel` on dispose):

```
public func response(request: URLRequest) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)> {
        return Observable.create { observer in

            // smart compiler should be able to optimize this out
            let d: Date?

            if URLSession.rx.shouldLogRequest(request) {
                d = Date()
            }
            else {
               d = nil
            }

            let task = self.base.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

                if URLSession.rx.shouldLogRequest(request) {
                    let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(d ?? Date())
                    print(convertURLRequestToCurlCommand(request))
                    #if os(Linux)
                        print(convertResponseToString(response, error.flatMap { $0 as NSError }, interval))
                    #else
                        print(convertResponseToString(response, error.map { $0 as NSError }, interval))
                    #endif
                }
                
                guard let response = response, let data = data else {
                    observer.on(.error(error ?? RxCocoaURLError.unknown))
                    return
                }

                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    observer.on(.error(RxCocoaURLError.nonHTTPResponse(response: response)))
                    return
                }

                observer.on(.next((httpResponse, data)))
                observer.on(.completed)
            }

            task.resume()

            return Disposables.create(with: task.cancel)
        }
    }
```